# passing parameter from bundle.getString to class Paragraph od droidText doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, parameter-passing

I don't know why variable `myInt` is null in some places in my code.

In these lines it is ok, so variable is not null:

```
myInt = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
titolo3.setText(myInt);
```

When I use variable `myInt` in `Paragraph p1=new Paragraph(myInt);`, it is null.

What can be the problem?

TwoFragment.java

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{
            
                private View v;
                Intent chooser=null;
                String myInt="";
            
                public TwoFragment() {
                    // Required empty public constructor
                }
            
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }
            
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
                    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
                    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
            
                            //sendemail();
                            createPDF();
                            viewPDF();
            
            
            
                        }
                    });
                    TextView titolo3 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
                    TextView titolo2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
                    TextView titolo4 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultpizze);
            
                    //TextView titolo = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità3);
            
                  /*  Bundle bundle2=getArguments();
                    if(bundle2 != null){
                        String string = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
                        titolo3.setText(string);
                    }*/
            
                    Bundle bundle2=getArguments();
                    if(bundle2 != null){
                        myInt = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
                       titolo3.setText(myInt);
                    }
            
                    Bundle bundle3=getArguments();
                    if(bundle3 != null){
                       // String myInt3 = bundle3.getString("totalebirre", null);
                       //  cazzo2=Integer.parseInt(myInt3);
                       int cazzo2=bundle3.getInt("totalebirre");
                        titolo2.setText(String.valueOf(cazzo2));
            
            
            
                    }
                    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
                    if(bundle != null){
                        // String myInt2 = bundle2.getString("totalepizze", null);
                        //   cazzo=Integer.parseInt(myInt2);
                        //titolo2.setText(myInt2);
                        String string=bundle.getString("scelta3", null);
                         titolo4.setText(string);
            
                    }
            
            
            
                    return rootView;
                }
               /* public void sendemail(){
            
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                    String[] to={"marco_marcoletto@hotmail.it"};
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ciao");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "zao");
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    chooser=intent.createChooser(intent,"manda email");
                    startActivity(chooser);
                }*/
               public void createPDF() {
            
                   Document doc = new Document();
            
                   try {
                       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                               .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";
            
                       File dir = new File(path);
                       if (!dir.exists())
                           dir.mkdirs();
            
                       Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);
            
                       File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
                       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            
                       PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
            
                       // open the document
                       doc.open();
                       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                               .getResources(), R.drawable.androtuto);
                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                       Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                       myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
            
                       // add image to document
                       doc.add(myImg);
            
                       Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(myInt);
                   Log.d("ciao",myInt);
        
                       Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
                       p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                       p1.setFont(paraFont);
            
                       // add paragraph to document
                       doc.add(p1);
            
                       Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Ciao");
                       Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                       p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                       p2.setFont(paraFont2);
            
                       doc.add(p2);
            
                       stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                               .getResources(), R.drawable.android);
                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                       myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                       myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
            
                       // add image to document
                       doc.add(myImg);
            
                       // set footer
                       Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Pied de page ");
                       HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
                       doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);
            
                   } catch (DocumentException de) {
                       Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                   } finally {
                       doc.close();
                   }
            
               }
                public void viewPDF(){
                    String path = "/sdcard/droidText/sample.pdf";
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
            
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
            
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            
            }
```

ThreeFragment.java

(Fragment from where I pass variables)

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    Planet p;
    String myInt="";



    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyListFragment mlf=new MyListFragment();

                mlf.showResult(v);
              // MyListFragment.showResult(v);
                showResult2(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }


        };


        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult2(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount = 0;
       // String a = "";


        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
              //  a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
      /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()) {


                result += "\n" + p.getName() + " " + p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                //totalAmount2+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
        }*/



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" +myInt + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
            bun2.putString("scelta2", result);
            TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
            transaction2.commit();

            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
           // bun.putString("totalebirre", a);
        bun.putInt("totalebirre", totalAmount);
            TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
            transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Main that calls three fragments:

```
public class MainBirra extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainbirra);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().

                replace(R.id.fragmentContainer2, new ThreeFragment()).commit();



    }
  /*  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("OnDestroy", " callback_2");
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Is `Log.d("ciao",myInt);` printing correct output ?

Comment: Have you tried moving that into onCreate instead of onCreateView ?

Comment: The way you have your code, as long as there's one bundle, your bundle, bundle2 and bundle3 will never be null. Why not just add and retrieve all your arguments on the same bundle?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion ,you can make a static methode that return instence of the fragment that you want to start, in this methode you will init you variables like myInt in TwoFragment.
So in TwoFragment.java add this methode

```
public static TwoFragment getInstance(String myInt){
TwoFragment twoFragment=new TwoFragment();
twoFragment.myInt=myInt;
return twoFragment;
}
```

and whene you need to start the fragment in other place use this code in place of default constructor

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    Planet p;
    String myInt="";



    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyListFragment mlf=new MyListFragment();

                mlf.showResult(v);
              // MyListFragment.showResult(v);
                showResult2(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }


        };


        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult2(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount = 0;
       // String a = "";


        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
              //  a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
      /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()) {


                result += "\n" + p.getName() + " " + p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                //totalAmount2+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
        }*/



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" +myInt + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            TwoFragment fgsearch2=TwoFragment.getInstance(result);
            fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
            transaction2.commit();






    }
}
```

Comment: where i must add TwoFragment twoFragment=TwoFragment.getInstance("value of you string");?

Comment: in TreeFragment.java replace
TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
by
TwoFragment twoFragment=TwoFragment.getInstance("value of you string");
so now you don't want to use bundle

Comment: sorry, can you write in complete mode? please?

Comment: where i must put the method getInstance?

Comment: method getInstance give me error "return twoFragment" and (String myInt)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    String myInt="";
    int cazzo2;
    String scelta3;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static TwoFragment getInstance(String myInt,int cazzo2,String scelta3){
        TwoFragment twoFragment=new TwoFragment();
        twoFragment.myInt=myInt;
        twoFragment.cazzo2=cazzo2;
        twoFragment.scelta3=scelta3;
        return twoFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //sendemail();
                createPDF();
                viewPDF();



            }
        });
        TextView titolo3 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        TextView titolo2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
        TextView titolo4 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultpizze);

        titolo3.setText(myInt);
        titolo2.setText(String.valueOf(cazzo2));
        titolo4.setText(scelta3);

        return rootView;
    }
    /* public void sendemail(){

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
         String[] to={"marco_marcoletto@hotmail.it"};
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ciao");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "zao");
         intent.setType("message/rfc822");
         chooser=intent.createChooser(intent,"manda email");
         startActivity(chooser);
     }*/
    public void createPDF() {

        Document doc = new Document();

        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";

            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

            File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            // open the document
            doc.open();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                    .getResources(), R.drawable.androtuto);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            // add image to document
            doc.add(myImg);

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(myInt);
            Log.d("ciao",myInt);

            Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);

            // add paragraph to document
            doc.add(p1);

            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Ciao");
            Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
            p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p2.setFont(paraFont2);

            doc.add(p2);

            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                    .getResources(), R.drawable.android);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            // add image to document
            doc.add(myImg);

            // set footer
            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Pied de page ");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } finally {
            doc.close();
        }

    }
    public void viewPDF(){
        String path = "/sdcard/droidText/sample.pdf";
        File targetFile = new File(path);
        Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and other fragment

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    Planet p;
    String myInt="";



    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyListFragment mlf=new MyListFragment();

                mlf.showResult(v);
                // MyListFragment.showResult(v);
                showResult2(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }


        };


        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult2(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount = 0;
        // String a = "";


        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
                //  a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
      /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()) {


                result += "\n" + p.getName() + " " + p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                //totalAmount2+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
        }*/



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" +myInt + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TwoFragment fgsearch2 = TwoFragment.getInstance(result,totalAmount,"test");
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();




    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i must pass content of variable "result" from three fragment to Two fragment....

Comment: where is "result" in TWO FRAGMENT?

Comment: whene we get instance of  TwoFragment we pass all variables

Comment: but here, public static TwoFragment getInstance(String myInt,int cazzo2,String scelta3) i must pass variable "result"?

Comment: yes result in TreeFragment.java, you will find it in myInt in TwoFragment.java

Comment: public static TwoFragment getInstance(String result,int cazzo2,String scelta3) ....twoFragment.myInt=result;....this i think that is correct

Comment: yes here whene we initalaze the variables of second fragments

Comment: but you don't write in this way public static TwoFragment getInstance(String result,int cazzo2,String scelta3) ....twoFragment.myInt=result;

Comment: i don't understand how you pass variable "result" from THREE FRAGMENT to TWO FRAGMENT....

Comment: parameter pass correctly from THREE to TWO FRAGMENT, but the problem is in paragraph(myInt)...in document i don't see content of variable "myInt"

Comment: can you help me,please?